# Fire an event when a liste get new item

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i have an empty  list :

```
<ul id="select2-choices"></ul>
```

this list gets elements added to it using a ui ,so i get this :

```
 <ul id="select2-choices">
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
 </ul>
```

i want to fire an event , in order to call a function when that list get a new item :

```
$("#select2-choices").on("Thevent", function (e)){
            self.SetDefaultTeam(e);
        });
```

how to do that ?

Comment: There is no event raised when content is added to the DOM. Do you control the JS code which is appending the new `li` element? If so you could manually raise an event using [`trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger). If you don't control the JS, then you could use a MutationObserver

Comment: What creates the list items and how? You left out an important part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mutation observers as shown below. The code is commented. I created a button to mimic the addition of new items, but the mutation observer is the function that recognises that change in the DOM tree.

**N.B.** If you have access to the code that is adding the new `li` then it would be better to trigger your function from there.

Let me know if you were hoping for something else.

---

```js
// Create a button to add options to mimic your functionality
$("#add-li").click(function() {
  $("ul#select2-choices").append("<li>New</li>");
});

// Create mutation observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  
    // Something has changed in the #select2-choices
    console.log("Change noticed in childList");
    
});

// Just look out for childList changes
var config = {
  attributes: false,
  childList: true,
  characterData: false
};

// Select target
var target = document.querySelector('#select2-choices');

// Launch observer with above configuration
observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="select2-choices">
</ul>

<button id="add-li">Add option</button>
```